# Pokemon Stats Breakdown

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

I am creating a Pokemon Battle simulator and I am looking for information on how the damage that each move deals is specifically calculated. (I know what attack and defense are, I'm looking for formulas.)  This is going to be a basic Gen I type sim, so I don't want to deal with Iv's and Ev's if possible.

Looking for info on what stats correlate with the moves themselves and how this is specifically incorporated with the attack /defense of pokemon.

Also, does Speed directly effect who goes first or does it just increase a percentage?

and also how is the multiplier for the *type* factor calculated?(Is it always just like 1.5 or 1 or .5, or is it more complicated)

*EDIT: I originally said "nature" but I really meant "type"*

Additional Questions:

1. Base stats refer to pokemon at level 50 correct?
2. Does anyone know where I can find tables of pokemon of gen 1 / their stats
3. Does anyone know where I can find a list of moves for gen 1
4. For 2 and 3 if anyone knows of tables that would let me view available moves/stats and pokemon stats by level that'd be AMAZING

Comment: Side Note: IVs and EVs were in Gen 1, but without a breeding mechanism to pass on IVs, and no way to reset EVs without resetting, it made it very hard to get a '6IV Battle Ready' Pokemon of today's calibre.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generally find all the information you're asking for at [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Main_Page).

For example, here's the [exact damage formula](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Damage#Damage_formula).

[Speed](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Stats#Speed) directly dictates who goes first; it's only random in case of a tied speed stat.

[Natures](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Nature#Explanation) always increase one stat by 10% and decrease another stat by 10%, or have no effect.

Additional answers:

1. Base stats are simply used in the [formula](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Stats#Determination_of_stats) for determining current stats. They don't necessarily correspond to stats at any level at all; they are just numbers that are meaningful relative to each other.
2. I prefer [Psypokes](http://www.psypokes.com/dex/index.php). For each Pokemon, you can change to see their stats, levelup moves, TMs, etc. for any generation where they existed.
3. Bulbapedia has a [list of all moves](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_moves), sorted by generation in which they were introduced.
4. [Psypokes](http://www.psypokes.com/dex/index.php) will show you moves by level, but for stats you will have to use [some formulas](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Stats#Determination_of_stats) from Bulbapedia.

Comment: So for the nature, if i use a flamethrower on a bulbasaur, my attack stat goes up 10% temporarily or his defense goes down, or both?

Comment: or you mean it increases the overall damage stat(post calculation) by 10%?

Comment: @LukeP You are confusing "nature" (which statically affects stats like Attack and Speed, etc.) and type effectiveness, which is where you see things like "super effective" or "not very effective". I suggest reading up on [damage modification](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Damage_modification) for a full description of how this works.

Comment: Natures didn't exist in Gen 1 anyway, did they?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol nope, they were introduced in Gen III